# SPARQL shows data source in results when using concat

Tags: string, concatenation, sparql, protege

I need to have the 2 strings values merge, but without the source code and the " " if possible. I tried everything but it's only giving me these results, which are the good results, but without the source code.

CODE:

```
SELECT (fn:concat ((str(?titre)), ". "  , (str(?membreDeST))) AS ?nom)

WHERE {?UER_ST   foaf:member  ?membreDeST .
?membreDeST foaf:title ?titre.

?membreDeST foaf:familyName  ?nomDeFamille.  FILTER(regex (str(?nomDeFamille), "Paquette", "i"))
}
```

RESULT:

```
"M. http://exemple.teluq.ca/ressources/Gilbert_Paquette"
```

RESULT I should have:

```
M.Gilbert_Paquette
```

The query that I did can extract the members who their family name is Paquette. And to be more precise I need to put the title of the person plus their complete name, for those who their family name is Paquette. If anyone one can help, it will be really appreciated.

Comment: best practice to model the human readable form of an RDF entity is to add an additional triple via e.g. `rdfs:label` predicate to the entity. This label can then be queried and used. So I strongly suggest to add labels to your data, doing string hacks on URIs is error prone and annoying.

Comment: if not, just replace the first part of the URI with an empty string, SPARQL `replace` function is the way to go.

Comment: also what happened to your previous question?

Comment: I was able to resolve it but forgot to remove it . I'm new here so not used to how things work. I'm going to try what you told me and be back with the results. Thank you !

Comment: Just a little  question , how do i add and additional triple with the Rdfs label, Because I tried everything and the book i'm using to study sparql isn't really clear on how to manage sparql on protege

Comment: the way StackOverflow works is to keep questions alive - should be quite obvious, how else could other people find solutions to possibly same issues?

Comment: with adding triples I mean add them to the data. If you're using Protege, you can add an annotations with `rdfs:label` as the property - this can be done for any entity, i.e. classes, properties and individuals. Querying the label then is just adding another triple pattern to your query

Comment: Hi again, been trying to understand and did every search to understand how I should do it but none of them is working. The book we are using is not explaining the prefix, but even that I understood everything but when I put rdfs. its not working. I tried creating another triple for the rdf:label , and even replaced the prefix foaf for rdfs.I’m really out of solutions.
 Can you please provide any example. And another thing when I use the rdfs. do I need to let go all of the str () ?